# How to change url for a page?

Tags: 7, uri

We have a production system xxx.org and a test system at test.xxx.org. We copy production to test.  Some of the URL's on the test system keep pointing to production where we want them to point to test.xxx.org.

The production URL looks like they are hard coded in the menu.

We want to easily move production to test so we can test the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the value of **$base_url** value on */sites/default/settings.php*. It may help. Also don't forget to clear the cache on your test site.

If the absolute URL in the menus is not specified directly on the menu items (through *Structure / Menus*) maybe it was embedded within the template and you'll have to search for the code on the .tpl files of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your /sites/default/settings.php and check your $base_url.

You can also try this:
Log into your Drupal admin panel. Go to Configuration page.
Click on URL aliases located under the Search and metadata section:
Click Add alias button:
Fill in the Existing system path and the Path alias. Save changes.